# Cassandra key cache optimization

Tags: caching, cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I want to optimize the key cache in cassandra. I know about the key_cache_size_in_mb: The capacity in megabytes of all key caches on the node. Now while increasing what stats I need to look in order to determine the increase is actually benefiting the system.
Currently with the default settings I am getting

Key Cache        : entries 20342, size 17.51 MB, capacity 100 MB, 4806 hits, 29618 requests, 0.162 recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds.

I have opsCenter up and running too. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at number of hits and recent hit rate.

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/maximizing-cache-benefit-with-cassandra